# How to make a print message when someone enters an invalid input (with no matches in the csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So here is my code, im new to python and I'm trying to make it print an error msg if your input does not match any data in the csv file, how do I make that?
I tried with (Line 9)

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('cheques.csv')
dt = datetime.now()

DNI = int(input('Ingrese su DNI: '))
if DNI != data[DNI]:
 print('DNI no existente')

tipoCheque = input('Ingrese el tipo de cheque (EMITIDO O DEPOSITADO): ').upper()
estadoCheque = input('Ingrese el estado del cheque (APROBADO, RECHAZADO o PENDIENTE): ').upper()


# str.contains revisa un dato tipo string

datoCliente = data[(data["DNI"] == (DNI)) & (data["Tipo"].str.contains(tipoCheque)) &(data["Estado"].str.contains(estadoCheque))]


salida = input('Ingrese el formato de salida de los datos(PANTALLA o CSV): ').upper()
if salida == 'PANTALLA':
 print(datoCliente)
elif salida == 'CSV':
 datoCliente.to_csv(f'{DNI}-{dt}.csv')
 print('Archivo CSV creado con éxito')
```

SOLVED

`if DNI not in data['DNI'].values.tolist():      print('DNI inexistente, intentelo de nuevo')     sys.exit()`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: SOLVED. 

`if DNI not in data['DNI'].values.tolist():

    print('DNI inexistente, intentelo de nuevo')
    sys.exit()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually verify if the given DNI is in your csv, however, you are not checking it properly. The problem is in this line:

```py
if DNI != data[DNI]:
    print("DNI no existe")
```

Note that `DNI` is the integer given by the user
(btw: if the user provides otherthing than an integer, for instance, a string like "45.565.565-7" it will fail), but you need to check the column called DNI:

```py
if DNI not in data["DNI"]:
    print("DNI no existe")
```

this is assuming the column is called `"DNI"`, rename it properly if needed.

Comment: Ty so much, but now everytime I write something in the input it returns the print message, even if the DNI exists in the csv

Comment: are you sure the DNI is in the dataframe?  maybe you are not reading the csv properly. In addition to this, make sure it is as integer, otherwise it fail anyway: check it with `print(df['DNI'].dtype)`

Comment: Yeah the code works fine without the input message so it is reading the csv file properly, [here you have the project in replit](https://replit.com/@NachSarasola/sprint4#main.py)